# Replace data in Pandas dataframe based on condition by locating index and replacing by the column's mode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hopefully, you don't mind me posting a question here instead of the regular stack exchange forum. I'm learning ML basics and practising pandas.

assuming the data frame is called df, column name = column name

Suppose I want to replace some 'dirty' values in the column 'column name'. There are "not known" values in this column that mean nothing so i would like to replace them with the mode.

```
df['columnname'].mode()
```

returns

```
0   dog
dtype: object
```

this code below replaces the "not known" values as NaN rather than the mode.

```
df.loc[df.index[df['columnname'] == "not known"].tolist(),'columnname'] = df['columnname'].mode()
```

what am i missing? or how should i fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your entire code is correct except at the last point where you are equating with `df['columnname'].mode()`. The value here should have a dtype int or string but this has a dtype object. Just replace it with `df['columnname'].mode().values` and you are good to go.

Also, I see a lot of stuff that is not required here. Since you are using `pd.loc`, you can simply write:

```
df.loc[df['columnname'] == "not known",'columnname'] = df['columnname'].mode().values
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['columnname'].replace({'not known' : df['columnname'].mode().values} , inplace=True)
```

This is the most direct and intuitive way of replacing values given you already know what the "dirty" value is.

Comment: Any chance you could explain how or why that should be tried?